# Plotting Two Datasets in One Chart with two y-axes Using the Library chart.js

Tags: javascript, html, graph, charts, chart.js

I wrote the following **CODE** using the chart.js library, which generates the **OUTPUT** displayed below. I'm seeking guidance on how to effectively control the labels on the horizontal axis.

## CODE

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    
    <canvas id="chart" width="1920" height="1080"></canvas>
    
    <script>
        
        const ctx = document.getElementById('chart').getContext('2d');

        const chart = new Chart(ctx, {
              type: 'line',
              data: {
                datasets: [
                  {
                    yAxisID: 'yA',
                    label: 'Data1',
                    data: [
                          { x: 0.05, y: 12 },
                          { x: 0.15, y: 19 },
                          { x: 0.25, y: 3 },
                          { x: 0.35, y: 5 },
                          { x: 0.45, y: 2 },
                          { x: 0.55, y: 3 },
                          ],
                  },
                  {
                    yAxisID: 'yB',
                    label: 'Data2',
                    data: [
                          { x: 0.0, y: 20 },
                          { x: 0.2, y: 1 },
                          { x: 0.3, y: 15 },
                          { x: 0.4, y: 2 },
                          { x: 0.5, y: 31 },
                          { x: 0.6, y: 11 },
                          ],
                  }
                ]
              },
              options: {
                        responsive: true,
                            scales: {
                                      yA: {
                                        type: 'linear',
                                        position: 'left',
                                        ticks: { beginAtZero: true, color: 'blue' },
                                        grid: { display: false }
                                      },
                                      yB: {
                                        type: 'linear',
                                        position: 'left',
                                        ticks: { beginAtZero: true, color: 'green' },
                                        grid: { display: false }
                                      },
                                      x: { ticks: { beginAtZero: true },
                                           }
                                    }
                        }
            });
        
    </script>
    
</body>
</html>
```

I attempted to plot two datasets in a single Chart.js chart using the provided code. I expected both datasets to be clearly visualized on the chart.

---

**SOLUTION**

Adding `type: 'linear'` to the x-axis scales options.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    
    <canvas id="chart" width="1920" height="1080"></canvas>
    
    <script>
        
        const ctx = document.getElementById('chart').getContext('2d');

        const chart = new Chart(ctx, {
              type: 'line',
              data: {
                datasets: [
                  {
                    yAxisID: 'yA',
                    label: 'Data1',
                    data: [
                          { x: 0.05, y: 12 },
                          { x: 0.15, y: 19 },
                          { x: 0.25, y: 3 },
                          { x: 0.35, y: 5 },
                          { x: 0.45, y: 2 },
                          { x: 0.55, y: 3 },
                          ],
                  },
                  {
                    yAxisID: 'yB',
                    label: 'Data2',
                    data: [
                          { x: 0.0, y: 20 },
                          { x: 0.2, y: 1 },
                          { x: 0.3, y: 15 },
                          { x: 0.4, y: 2 },
                          { x: 0.5, y: 31 },
                          { x: 0.6, y: 11 },
                          ],
                  }
                ]
              },
              options: {
                        responsive: true,
                            scales: {
                                      yA: {
                                        type: 'linear',
                                        position: 'left',
                                        ticks: { beginAtZero: true, color: 'blue' },
                                        grid: { display: false }
                                      },
                                      yB: {
                                        type: 'linear',
                                        position: 'left',
                                        ticks: { beginAtZero: true, color: 'green' },
                                        grid: { display: false }
                                      },
                                      x: { ticks: { beginAtZero: true },
                                           type: 'linear',}
                                    }
                        }
            });
        
    </script>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add the labels and `datasets` format is not as per the [doc](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/samples/line/multi-axis.html)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    
    <canvas id="chart" width="1920" height="1080"></canvas>
    
    <script>
        const ctx = document.getElementById('chart').getContext('2d');

        const labels = ['0.05', '0.1', '0.15', '0.2', '0.25', '0.3', '0.35', '0.4', '0.45', '0.5', '0.55', '0.6'];

        const chart = new Chart(ctx, {
            type: 'line',
            data: {
                labels: labels,
                datasets: [
                    {
                        yAxisID: 'yA',
                        label: 'Data1',
                        data: [12, 0, 19, 0, 3, 0, 5, 0, 2, 0, 3, 0], // Insert zeros for non-existent labels
                    },
                    {
                        yAxisID: 'yB',
                        label: 'Data2',
                        data: [0, 20, 0, 1, 0, 15, 0, 2, 0, 31, 0, 11], // Insert zeros for non-existent labels
                    }
                ]
            },
            options: {
                responsive: true,
                scales: {
                    yA: {
                        type: 'linear',
                        position: 'left',
                        ticks: { beginAtZero: true, color: 'blue' },
                        grid: { display: false }
                    },
                    yB: {
                        type: 'linear',
                        position: 'left',
                        ticks: { beginAtZero: true, color: 'green' },
                        grid: { display: false }
                    },
                    x: { ticks: { beginAtZero: true }}
                }
            }
        });
    </script>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: hello Jai248 thanks a lot. but with your solution the labels on the x axis is not ordered (highlighted in green rectangle above)

Comment: Hey Marko I ordered the x axis label, please do necessary changes as you need in labels and y axis values, please accept the answer :)

Comment: hello Jai248 thanks a lot. is it also possible to define labels for instance [0.0, 0.3, 0.6] and the  (x,y) datapoints will plot correctly?

Comment: yeah they will plot

Comment: i mean for instance  labels=[0.0, 0.3, 0.6] and data=[{ x: 0.1, y: 20 },{ x: 0.2, y: 1 },      { x: 0.3, y: 15 },{ x: 0.4, y: 2 },{ x: 0.5, y: 31 },{ x: 0.6, y: 11 },] would that be possible?

Comment: yeah it should work you already did using heard's solution

Answer (score 0):

Based on the code snippet and the issue described, it seems that you're having trouble with the horizontal (x-axis) labels in your Chart.js graph. To manage the labels on the horizontal axis, you need to configure the scales option in your chart configuration, specifically the x axis part.

From your code, I notice that you're using data points with an x value that is a decimal. If you want these to appear as labels on the x-axis, you'll need to specify the labels array in the data object of your chart configuration. However, Chart.js expects the labels array to be at the same level as datasets for the x-axis labels when you're not using a time series.

Here's a high-level example of how you might specify labels:

```
data: {
  labels: [/* array of labels corresponding to your data points */],
  datasets: [/* your datasets here */]
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot. I added you code you recommended in my code above. Please check if its correct like this. I highligted you code with a green rectangle. it looks perfect but the x avlues from Data1 are not correct in the graph (highlighted with green arrows).